# Solve system to find critical points.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, systems-of-equations

Hi I have to find the stationary points for 
$$f(x)= x^4+y^4-(x-y)^2.$$
So far i founded the partial derivatives for $x$ and $y$.

Next step is to solve this system to get my critical points:
$$
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
2x^3-x+y=0 \\ 
2y^3-y+x=0
\end{array}
\right. 
$$
But I don't really know how can I solve this system without having to substitute $y=x-2x^3$ and then raise at the power of $3$.

Comment: Add the two equations to get $2x^3=-2y^3$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding the two equations gives
$$2x^3+2y^3=0\\
\implies x^3+y^3=0$$
See [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=stationary+points+of+f%28x%29%3Dx%5E4%2By%5E4%E2%88%92%28x%E2%88%92y%29%5E2):

http://www4b.wolframalpha.com/Calculate/MSP/MSP3171205d4eh2905ci3e900002931gcaia784ic6i?MSPStoreType=image/gif&s=36&w=300.&h=237.&cdf=Resizeable&cdf=Rotation